# Quadratic Equations Factored Form

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a beginner with python as my first language trying to factor a 
quadratic where the equation provides the result in
factor form for example:

`x^2+5x+4`

Output to be (or any factors in parenthesis)

`(x+4)(x+1)`

So far this only gives me x but not a correct value either

**CODE**

```
def quadratic(a,b,c):
    x = -b+(((b**2)-(4*a*c))**(1/2))/(2*a)
    return x

print quadratic(1,5,4)
```

Comment: Your equation has brackets placed incorrectly. it should be `x = (-b+((b**2)-(4*a*c))**(1/2))/(2*a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are in the wrong places, you're only calculating and returning one root, and (most importantly), you're using **(1/2) to calculate the square root. In Python 2, this will evaluate to 0 (integer arithmetic). To get 0.5, use (1./2) (or 0.5 directly).
This is (slightly) better:

```
def quadratic(a,b,c):
    x1 = (-b+(b**2 - 4*a*c)**(1./2))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b-(b**2 - 4*a*c)**(1./2))/(2*a)
    return x1, x2

print quadratic(1,5,4)
```

and returns `(-1.0, -4.0)`.
To get your parentheses, put the negative of the roots in an appropriate string:

```
def quadratic(a,b,c):
    x1 = (-b+(b**2 - 4*a*c)**(1./2))/(2*a)
    x2 = (-b-(b**2 - 4*a*c)**(1./2))/(2*a)
    return '(x{:+f})(x{:+f})'.format(-x1,-x2)

print quadratic(1,5,4)
```

Returns:

```
(x+1.000000)(x+4.000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
from __future__ import division
def quadratic(a,b,c):
    x = (-b+((b**2)-(4*a*c))**(1/2))/(2*a)
    y = (-b-((b**2)-(4*a*c))**(1/2))/(2*a)
    return x,y

m,n = quadratic(1,5,4)
sign_of_m = '-' if m > 0 else '+'
sign_of_n = '-' if n > 0 else '+'
print '(x'+sign_of_m+str(abs(m))+')(x'+sign_of_n+str(abs(n))+')'
```

Output

```
(x+1.0)(x+4.0)
```

Let me know if it helps.